# How does rails typically know what environment to run under?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i.e. when I'm running the app in test mode (using rails server) or maybe some other configuration it's running in develop mode (with no asset compilation, or caching, etc) but when I deploy it to a server its running in production mode.

How does the app determine what environment configuration to use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rails reads the current environment from the operating system's environment variables by checking the following in order of priority:

1. Get the value of the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable by calling `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`
2. If the above is nil, then get `ENV["RACK_ENV"]`
3. If the above is nil, then make it equal to `"development"`

You can see that behavior in the Rails source code by looking at the definition of the `Rails.env` method:

```
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails.rb#L55-L57

That's the method you call when you write `Rails.env` to find out the current environment.

Comment: Ah, I see. So typically when people deploy to a server instance they make sure there is an environment variable RAILS_ENV='production' or whatever they want is that right?

Comment: That is correct. That's also the reason you use `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails server` if you want to run your app locally in production mode.